# PHP - array wrong output (need function help)

Tags: php, arrays, function

In the output of this function (at the end) you can see that the products are placed in every subArray. I want to pass through the function via an argument where the product needs to be added. The argument will be a variable on a different page: like if the variable has value "meal2" => product only needs to be added under array "meal2".

```
function addToMeal() {

    $xmaaltijden = $_SESSION['xmaaltijden'];
    $i=1;

    while ( $i <= $xmaaltijden ) {

        $schemas = array('maaltijd' . $i);
        $i++;


    $producten = $_SESSION['products'];

    foreach ($schemas as $key => $schema){
        foreach ($producten as $k => $product){

             $variables[$schema][] = $product;
    };
};
};

echo '<pre>' . print_r($variables,1) . '</pre>';  
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [meal1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 9
        )

    [meal2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 9
        )

    [meal3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 9
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not:

```
 foreach ($schemas as $key => $schema){
        foreach ($producten as $k => $product){

             $variables[$schema][] = $product;
    };
```

But:

```
$yourVar = 'meal2';
foreach ($schemas as $key => $schema){
   if ($schema === $yourVar) {
       $variables[$schema] = $producten;
   } else {
       $variables[$schema] = array();
   }
}
```

Comment: how can i print everything?

Comment: print_r($variables);

Comment: My code is adding products to your specific name and for others schemas it set empty array.

Comment: yes i know, but how can i print every array and values

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you now. Can you show me example of output you want to receive?

Comment: like if i have 3 meals, i want to see: meal1: (all products from meal1), meal2: (all products in array meal2) etc..

Comment: But you said that at one time you have only one meal. If you want keep all data during different request you must use session